# Unexpected element &quot;{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project&quot; {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, minecraft

This is the first time I have tried to make a minecraft plugin, and I get this error:
[image: this error]

I am not a programmer, so can some one say why I had this error when I go in build.xml?

Eclipse version : 4.20.0

build.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 

  <groupId>test.plugin.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-Complete</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>main test</name>

  <description>test</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the software reading the file is expecting Ant stuff but found something else, which it could not interpret.  Indeed `build.xml` is a typical name for a build file used by Ant, but the contents shown appear to be meant to be saved as a `pom.xml` file to be used by Maven.  A good first step might be to correct the filename; perhaps then the program would read it in the right frame of mind.